# not able to get html view after linking angular app to index.html using ui-view

Tags: html, angularjs

My HTML pages are not getting routed via ui-view used in index.html. However 
I defined all declarations in my controller. I used $stateProvider in my controller to get into a particular HTML. This is showing 
"....index.html#/welcome" in browser URL location but nothing is displayed into the page. Please help me to get out of this situation.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link    rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome-
 4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular-loading-bar/loading-
 bar.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="bower_components/chosen/chosen.css">
            <!-- endbuild --> 



            <!-- build:css content/css/main.css -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/bootstrap-
select.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/common.css">
        </head >

        <body >

            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an 
<strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a 
href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your 
experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->
       <div>
            <div  class="body-overlay" style="z-index:1051;">
                <div class="overlay-content" id="bodyOverlayContent">
                     <p></p> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-section" ng-app="testApp">
                <div ui-view="welcome" ng-cloak>

            </div> 
     </div>
    </div>


                <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="angular-ui-router.js"></script>
            <script src="mytest.controller.js"></script>  
            <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

mytest.controller.js

```
  var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.router']);

  app.config(['$stateProvider', 
  '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('welcome', {
        url : '/welcome',
        templateUrl : 'welcome.html',
       controller : 'testController'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome');
    console.log($stateProvider);

  }]);

  app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
    $scope.showInfoMessages="Contact Information";
  });
```

welcome.html

```
  <div><p> Hi </p></div>
```

Comment: ng-app="testApp" Please assign this in HTML tag and put all Angularjs file in the head tag.

Comment: I did that but still the page is blank.

Comment: <div ui-view="" ></div>

Comment: Still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the string assign to `ui-view`

change

```
  <div ui-view="welcome" ng-cloak>
```

to this

```
 <div ui-view ng-cloak=""></div>
```

also add the `ng-app` on `html` tag

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TEwvJCF44L7z1TW9NG84?p=preview)

Comment: Still its displaying a blank page.

Comment: did you check the demo. try to add the same script urls

Comment: In Demo, there is no ui routing anywhere. What changes should I make?

Comment: opps my bad check it again

Comment: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.router' is not available!

Comment: remove your ui router and add this script `<script data-require="ui-router@0.3.1" data-semver="0.3.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>`

Comment: I used only those sripts which you mentioned but still getting this error.

Comment: can u create a plnkr

Comment: @Vimal make sure to check this as an answer if this heled